# How can I use Invoke-Wuinstall silently

Tags: powershell, windows-update

```
$WUInstallScript = { Import-Module C:\Path\PSWindowsUpdate.psm1; Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll -AutoReboot}
Invoke-WUInstall -ComputerName $hostname -Script $WUInstallScript
```

I am running this command but Invoke-WUInstall pops up 
that whether I want to confirm this action.
I want to invoke this silently. Is there any option to do this?

Comment: You should ask the creator of this module : [on technet]( http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc/view/Discussions#content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-Confirm:$false` switch like this:

```
Invoke-WUInstall -ComputerName $hostname -Script $WUInstallScript -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: It doesn't make it run silently.  Updates still pop-up GUIs (like Microsoft Security Essentials, etc.). -- How do you get it to actually run silently?

Answer (score 0):

I use a wu.ps1 file containing:

```
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Invoke-Command  {Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll -AutoReboot -Confirm:$FALSE}
```

and then something like:

```
powershell -file "C:\usr\wu.ps1"
```